# Form does not submit with load callback

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, callback

I am having difficulties loading a page within an iframe as a callback to form submission. When I submit the form without a callback, the submission works fine, but when I try to load a page after submitting the form, the form does not submit.

The following works:

```
$("#new_explanation").on('submit', function(ev){
});
```

The following does not work:

```
$("#new_explanation").on('submit', function(ev){
    $('#lastExplanation').load("http://localhost:3000/lasturl", function(){
      alert('hi world');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Iframe tag in html:

```
<iframe width="100%" id="lastExplanation"></iframe>
```

I think the return false is preventing the form from submitting, but I'm not sure how to do it without the page refreshing. Help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to post any html or rails.

Comment: What are the `iframe` elements in your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you use jQuery. Why don't you rely on jQuery's method *$.ajax*. It supports GET and POST request.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Just collect the data from the form, transform it to a json object and pass it to *data* property.

Answer (score 1):

1. Basic form submission means to have a refresh of the browser.
   If you don't want a refresh, you will have to do AJAX form submission.
2. Sure `return false` is a prevention of form submission.
3. My suggestion is as same as Krasimir's, all you have to do is trigger an AJAX form submission, then code whatever you want to do inside the function of the `done()` event handle.

BTW, never use `load()` method with an external url as parameter, it won't work.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to load a page inside the `iframe`, you just have to put the attribute "src" of your `iframe`. You can do this :

http://jsfiddle.net/2bZDy/

```
$("#new_explanation").on('submit', function(ev){
        $('#lastExplanation').attr("src", "http://localhost:3000/lasturl");
        return false;
    });
```